# How to retrieve data as an array using Firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just finished an Angular course and a couple of YouTube tutorials, and I'm trying to make my own web app. I successfully stored data in Firebase and now I'm trying to retrieve it. But I have this error, and I found out that I'm not retrieving an array. Any tips or suggestions on how to fix this error?

> TypeError: users.map is not a function

Here's my service:

```
private baseUrl: string = 'https://registrationcrud-1164a-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/registration.json';
private users: User[] = [];
usersChanged = new Subject<User[]>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

postRegistration(registerObj: User) {
  return this.http.post<User>(`${this.baseUrl}`, registerObj)
}

getRegisteredUser() {
  return this.http.get<User[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`)
  .pipe(
    map(users => {
     return users.map(user => {
      return {
        ...user,
        goals: user.goals ? user.goals: []
       };
     });
   }),
   tap(users => {
     this.setUsers(users);
   })
  );
}

setUsers(users: User[]){
  this.users = users;
  this.usersChanged.next(this.users.slice());
}
```

My component:

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.getUsers();
}

getUsers() {
  this.api.getRegisteredUser().subscribe(result => { 
    if (Array.isArray(result)) { 
      this.users = result; 
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.users); 
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; 
      this.dataSource.sort = this.matsort; 
    } else { 
      console.error("Received data is not an array:", result); 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

[image: Response]

[image: Firebase Database]

Comment: *TypeError: users.map is not a function*, highly suspect that `users` is not an array. Would be great if you could provide the received JSON response int he question. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun Thank you for responding. I have updated it. I'm not sure why this is not working since, I followed this instruction or code from a different tutorial and I tried to apply it on my own app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response received is an object but not an array. You should convert to an array with either of these methods:

1. Iterating the keys via [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
Object.keys(response).map((k: string) => response[k])
  .map((user: any) => ({
    ...user,
    goals: user.goals ?? []
})
```

2. Iterating the values via [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```
Object.values(response).map((v: any) => v)
  .map((user: any) => ({
    ...user,
    goals: user.goals ?? []
})
```

3. Iterating the entries via [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```
Object.entries(response).entries([k, v] => v)
  .map((user: any) => ({
    ...user,
    goals: user.goals ?? []
})
```

```
getRegisteredUser(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}`)
  .pipe(
    map((response: { [key: string]: User }) => {
     return Object.keys(response).map((k: string) => response[k])
       .map((user: User) => ({
         ...user,
         goals: user.goals ?? []
       }))
   }),
   tap(users =>{
     this.setUsers(users)
   })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful. If I encounter this error again, I know what to do!! Thank you very much!!

Comment: You are welcome. You may also have a read on my latest answer with alternatives on iterating the key-value pair to array.